# add_library generated by a custom_command

Tags: cmake

There is a `custom_command()` that hacked to assemble built object files from another big 3rd party open-source project. It produces an `*.a` library file.

The goal is to package it with CPack. Is there a way to do something like `add_library(... STATIC ...)` to it, so cmake could create a library-target that is then recognized correctly by CPack and placed to correct library directory within the resulting package?

Comment: Are you looking for [*imported* targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets)?

Comment: @Torbjörn, probably. There is a duplicate question but no usable code in it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274577/custom-target-as-a-target-library-in-cmake

Comment: Well, there is all the code you need. `add_library(... IMPORTED)` and `set_target_properties(... IMPORTED_LOCATION ...)`. In case you wonder: `install(TARGET ...)` for an imported target is not (yet) supported by CMake (3.6).

Comment: @Torbjörn, imported targets are not installable.

Comment: You can as a workaround use the `install(FILE ... )` maybe in combination of `get_property(fancy_lib_location TARGET fancy_lib PROPERTY LOCATION)` to have some dynamic pathing.