# CMake add_custom_command with target_link_libraries

Tags: cmake, dependencies, static-libraries, cmake-custom-command

For a number of reasons I have to manually generate a static library through a custom command.

However, it seems that the custom command is only executed when a *target* specifically requests its output files.

If I try to link the generated static library with `target_link_libraries`, CMake complains that it cannot find a rule to generate it.

```
# Building library on the fly
add_custom_command(OUTPUT mylib.a
    COMMAND ...
)
add_executable(myexe main.cpp)                                                                                                                                                     
target_link_libraries(myexe mylib.a) # Fails miserably
```

I imagine I have to insert a target or dependency somehow between the `add_custom_command` call and the `target_link_libraries` one, but I cannot understand how to do so correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For preserve dependency between executable and library file, you need to use **full path** to the library file when link with it:

```
target_link_libraries(my_exe ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mylib.a)
```

When use relative path, CMake expects library to be found *by the linker* (according to its rules), so CMake cannot adjust dependency with the library file in that case..

Comment: Hm, so CMake tracks only changing in the library file without binding to `add_custom_command`. Looks like you need to resort to IMPORTED library target, as described [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274577/custom-target-as-a-target-library-in-cmake). BTW that question looks like duplicate for yours.

Comment: Yeah it looks like it's the same problem, couldn't find it before.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do this to invoke MATLAB's RTW to build DLLs for me.  The function I used was `add_custom_target`.

```
add_custom_target(Name [ALL] [command1 [args1...]]
                  [COMMAND command2 [args2...] ...]
                  [DEPENDS depend depend depend ... ]
                  [BYPRODUCTS [files...]]
                  [WORKING_DIRECTORY dir]
                  [COMMENT comment]
                  [VERBATIM] [USES_TERMINAL]
                  [COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS]
                  [SOURCES src1 [src2...]])
```

For you it may look like this:

```
add_custom_target(MyLib ALL 
                  <Put your command here>
                  COMMENT "Building MyLib"
                  )
add_executable(MyExe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyExe MyLib)
```

If that doesn't work I've heard that you can use `add_library()` to create a dummy library. Then, use `set_target_properties()` to create an INTERFACE property for it.

Refences:

[add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/add_custom_target.html)